# Express.js Avoid reload the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, mustache

currently I have no solution for a site which I am trying to build. The page is not that big but I want to achieve that the complete site does not reload when I am opening a new tab in the navbar. I am using express.js and mustache as the template engine. 
My goal is, that only the content reloads and not the whole site including the Navbar.

Do I have to use Ajax here?  and

Is my structure correct to do this?

On the Server.js file I have this general structure I am not sure if there is a trick with views to only reload the content part of a page:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html')
});

app.get('/navitem1', function(req, res) {
    res.render('navitem1.html')
});

app.get('/navitem2', function(req, res) {
    res.render('navitem2.html')
});
```

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't reload? it returns a time out error?

Comment: See `caching`. https://evanhahn.com/express-dot-static-deep-dive/

Comment: you need to cache your content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make sure your webpage doesn't reload while switch tabs and you're webpage isn't that big. I would recommend containing all your information within one .html file, have each "page" contained by a div with a targetable id, then simply hide/show the content that is selected. You might want to check out page.js and jquery they make this process much easier.

This is a quick demo of how to implement this:

note: you will need to **npm init** and **npm i page**

index.html:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="title-area">
   <h1>--your title--</h1>
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="/anotherpage">Another Page</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="home">
   --home content--
  </div>
  <div id="another-page">
   --other page content--
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/scripts/page.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/routes.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

scripts/controllers/routes.js:

sorry about globally scoped the IFFE functions, this is copy pasted.

```
'use strict';
(function(module){
const homeController = {};
homeController.init = function(){
  $('#another-page').hide();
  $('title').html('Home');
  $('#home').fadeIn('slow');
}
module.homeController = homeController;
})(window);

(function(module){
const anotherpageController = {};
anotherpageController.init = function(){
  $('#home').hide();
  $('title').html('anotherpage');
  $('#another-page').fadeIn('slow');
}
module.anotherpageController = anotherpageController;
})(window);

page('/', homeController.init);
page('/anotherpage', anotherpageController.init);

page();
```

if you'd like a better demo you can check out the app I built (where most of this content was ripped) https://github.com/loganabsher/portfolio-2.0

Comment: Please provide an example to your answer. Example with codes. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Ok thanks thats what I thought as well after reading a little bit more. One more thing i am not sure. If the site grows and getting bigger does it still make sense to keep everything in one html file and handle them with hide show or are the other smarter techniques. For example ajax.

Comment: I'd say it's generally standard to have one main html page, but that obviously depends on what you are trying to do. Are you trying to make a static web page or an actual web app?

Comment: It will be a small admin panel where I can load MemberList tables and modify them. Also some simple forms to add stuff.